# What is QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP_UTF8 for in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I cannot find any official documentation about QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP_UTF8 macro.
How does it works and what is "scope" argument? Is it namespace? And if it is, how to specify nested namespaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found documentation for it (it is hard to find but it is documented):

[- Global Qt Declarations | Qt Core 6.3.2](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtglobal.html#QT_TR_NOOP)

> #### QT_TR_NOOP(*sourceText*)
>
> Marks the UTF-8 encoded string literal *sourceText* for delayed translation in the current context (class).
>
> The macro tells lupdate to collect the string, and expands to *sourceText* itself.
>
> Example:
>
> ```cpp
> FriendlyConversation::greeting(int type) 
> {
>      static const char *greeting_strings[] = {
>         QT_TR_NOOP("Hello"),
>         QT_TR_NOOP("Goodbye") 
>     }; 
>     return tr(greeting_strings[type]);
> }
> ```
>
> **The macro QT_TR_NOOP_UTF8() is identical and obsolete; this applies to all other _UTF8 macros as well**.
>
> **See also** [QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtglobal.html#QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP)() and [Internationalization with Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/internationalization.html).

Note bold part. So doesn't matter that this is for `QT_TR_NOOP` it applies also for:

[- Global Qt Declarations | Qt Core 6.3.2](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtglobal.html#QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP)

> #### QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP(*context*, *sourceText*)
>
> Marks the UTF-8 encoded string literal *sourceText* for delayed translation in the given *context*. The *context* is typically a class name and also needs to be specified as a string literal.
>
> The macro tells lupdate to collect the string, and expands to *sourceText* itself.
>
> Example:
>
> ```cpp
> static const char *greeting_strings[] = {
>     QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP("FriendlyConversation", "Hello"),
>     QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP("FriendlyConversation", "Goodbye")
> };
>
> QString FriendlyConversation::greeting(int type)
> {
>     return tr(greeting_strings[type]);
> }
>
> QString global_greeting(int type)
> {
>     return qApp->translate("FriendlyConversation",
>                            greeting_strings[type]);
> }
> ```
>
> **See also** [QT_TR_NOOP](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtglobal.html#QT_TR_NOOP)(), [QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP3](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtglobal.html#QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP3)(), and [Internationalization with Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/internationalization.html).

Comment: So what's the difference with the documented `QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP` which does exactly the same thing?

Comment: @Thomas got documentation for it - doc says: "no difference".

Answer (score 0):

There is [only a single mention](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/search?q=QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP_UTF8) of this macro in the `qtbase` repository:

```
#define QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP_UTF8(scope, x) x
```

The macro has been there, almost unchanged and entirely undocumented, since at least 2011. It might be a backwards compatibility thing, but if so, it goes *way* back.

From [what I can tell](https://github.com/qt/qttools/search?q=QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP_UTF8), the translation tool Qt Linguist treats it in the same way as the more "official" [`QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtglobal.html#QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP) macro, which incidentally also accepts UTF-8 only.